# Pythonic handling of leading whitespace in """triple quote"" strings... modifying args of user-created exception during exception __init__()?

Tags: python, string, exception, multiline

I'm trying to modify the message an exception is constructed with on raising it, but much to my surprise, the actual arg passed is what's caught in `except`, not any values internal to the exception.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```py
class ScriptError(Exception):
    """This is our special exception class so we can catch it & 
    nicely print it in a popup message.
    """
    def ___init___(self, message):
        self.message = self.clean(message)

    def clean(message):
        """This clears whitespace at the start of each line for multiline strings.
        Required for the big triple-quote strings to both be formatted nicely in the
        code and also render properly in the tkinter popups.
        """
        return '\n'.join([line.lstrip() for line in str(message).split('\n')])
```

I'm trying to do this because this type of exception tend to be multi-line creatures:

```py
    if not any([status.getCurrentUser() in groups[group] for group in groups]):
        raise ScriptError("""You do not have permission to continue.
                             You must be in one of the following permitted groups:
                             {}""".format(config['permitted_groups']))
```

That sadly incorporate a bunch of leading whitespace from being written indented in the triple-quote syntax.

Now, this might be a classic XY problem, and I really need to just use a different format for my strings, like `("" "" "")`. However, that doesn't feel very pythonic; neither does bumping the aforementioned `clean` function out of the `ScriptError` namespace & into the main namespace, just to use it when displaying or raising the function.

Surely there's a nice, elegant way to do this?

Comment: Was `self.message = clean(message)` supposed to be `self.message = self.clean(message)`?

Comment: Ah yeah, I pulled `clean()` into the `ScriptError` namespace for this question without actually running it as such

Comment: It's more than just a namespace when the class starts doing descriptor stuff to the function.

Comment: Thanks, the answer below is a helpful note but does not answer my question.

Comment: I am actually not sure what the problem is. Can you show a [mcve] that illustrates what is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The standard library provides `textwrap.dedent` for this purpose.

```
>>> import text wrap
>>> help(textwrap.dedent)
Help on function dedent in module textwrap:

dedent(text)
    Remove any common leading whitespace from every line in `text`.

    This can be used to make triple-quoted strings line up with the left
    edge of the display, while still presenting them in the source code
    in indented form.

    Note that tabs and spaces are both treated as whitespace, but they
    are not equal: the lines "  hello" and "\thello" are
    considered to have no common leading whitespace.

    Entirely blank lines are normalized to a newline character.
```

Personally, I would make the caller of `ScriptError` be responsible for providing a properly dedented string.

```
class ScriptError(Exception):
    def ___init___(self, message):
        self.message = message


if not any([status.getCurrentUser() in groups[group] for group in groups]):
    msg = textwrap.dedent(
      """You do not have permission to continue.
         You must be in one of the following permitted groups:
         {}""".format(config['permitted_groups']
    )
    raise ScriptError(msg)
```

But you can just use `textwrap.dedent` in place of your `clean` function.

Comment: Awesome! Is there anyway to put this straight in an exception constructor rather than rely on future authors to remember to call it with `ExceptionName(textwrap.dedent("blah blah"))`?

Comment: I might consider redefining `ScriptError` (or creating a subclass) to take just the list of permitted groups as an argument, and construct the entire error message internally.

Comment: (`raise NotInGroupError(config['permitted_groups'])`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using it for a whole slew of different things, unfortunately. I could define unique exceptions for each one. Maybe I'll end up doing that.